# JW Player Playlist with listbar wont appear in xcode

Tags: html, objective-c, jwplayer

I'm making a simple jw player playlist with a listbar at the bottom. This will be shown in a ios app. The problem is it is only the first song that is showing.

**like this:**

[image]

On the internet it look like this

http://ratemyplays.com/home.html

which is correct.

Why is it not showing the same things in the app and on the internet?

**objective-c:**

```
webView.delegate = self;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

**html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/NwqHmnPBEeORiiIACmOLpg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 340px;">

 <div id='myElement'></div>
 <script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        playlist: [{
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeQ31jQNAVI&",
        image: "/uploads/sintel.jpg",
        title: "THIS IS A TEST",
        description: "Sintel is a fantasy CGI movie from the Blender Open Movie Project."
        },{
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEXSxUraLCI",
        image: "/uploads/tears.jpg",
        title: "THIS IS A TEST",
        description: "A complete open pipeline was used to produce this visual effect film."
        },{
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBZ_w2c6BTo",
        image: "/uploads/bunny.jpg",
        title: "THIS IS A TEST",
        description: "This  animated film is made using free and open source software."
        },{
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jTKtlb9cf4",
        image: "/uploads/elephants.jpg",
        title: "THIS IS A TEST",
        description: "This is the worlds first open movie, made entirely with Blender."
        }],
        width: 305,
        height: 600,
        listbar: {
        position: "bottom",
        size: 280
        }
    });
     </script>
</script></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Question edited completely and new information provided after uploading it to the internet.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. Are you embedding into a WebView? Please note, we don't support YouTube HTML5 yet, it just falls back to a single YouTube embed, until 6.8, that is.

Comment: yes i'm embedding into a webview. So the only way i can make a playlist is to embed a youtube playlist? Or is there someway i can make a html5 playlist or will i have to wait for 6.8.

Comment: You can't use YouTube, it won't work on mobile as a playlist yet. They will have to be mp4 files in the playlist instead.

Comment: Thats a shame. But thank you

Comment: Np. For 6.8 this should be fixed though.

Comment: Any official statements about the release?

Comment: Nothing officially, but it is set to be released in February.